# how to prevent user when opening a new tab,minimising,maximising in browser using javascript jquery

Tags: asp.net

I have to restrict the user of opening new tab,minimizing or opening another browser while running a web page.

Is there any way for me to make this happening?

Comment: Why? There must be a reason but I don't see it. Many times a programmer will get a requirement to do something which should not actually be done. Better to ask for the reason to do something and then, based on that, investigate the problem and possible solutions instead of starting with the solution which might wrong from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

One liner answer, you can't. You can control your page certain extend programmatically by restricting resize of the window or make it full screen  but you can't restrict users minimizing or opening another browser while running a web page.

Click **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110166/how-can-we-programmatically-enter-and-exit-the-fullscreen-mode-in-javascript)** for details of browser full screen mode programmatically, this full screen mode provides an illusion of restricting of another browser opening by hiding the options. But that's not the case, once user exit from full screen everything will be back in original state, so users can perform minimizing or opening another browser or a new tab.