# How to make google chrome go full screen in Angular 4 Application?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, angular6

I am developing an application where I want to implement such a thing where if user leaves from one component & enters other component, then in other component's ngOnInit method chrome browser should go full screen same as when we press Fn + F11 Key.

Any help or references are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we programmatically enter and exit the fullscreen mode in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110166/how-can-we-programmatically-enter-and-exit-the-fullscreen-mode-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913111/firefox-browser-rejected-fullscreen-change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with `requestFullscreen`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://angular-awqvmd.stackblitz.io/)**

```
fullScreen() {
    let elem = document.documentElement;
    let methodToBeInvoked = elem.requestFullscreen ||
      elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem['mozRequestFullscreen']
      ||
      elem['msRequestFullscreen'];
    if (methodToBeInvoked) methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);
}
```

Comment: Tried Brother It gives me this error -> Property 'mozRequestFullScreen' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement

Comment: Sure I want when i go from one component to other component it should automatically trigger

Comment: Brother this  works fine but user needs to press i want to do automatically so i just called your function directly from ngOnInit now it is show this error -> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Comment: You can't force a website to display in fullscreen mode.

Imagine the security concerns if that were possible.
Malicious websites could "Hijack" a less computer literate person's desktop for all kinds of dubious business.

All of JS fullscreen api's will throw a error like this:
"Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture." If you try to simply call it from your code.

Comment: @KrishnaRathore I tried to put the script in ngOnInit. It didn't work. Can you please help me... Thanks in advance...

Comment: document.exitFullscreen in order to exit fullscreen?

Answer (score 39):

How To - Fullscreen - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp

This is the current "angular way" to do it.

**HTML**

```
<h2 (click)="openFullscreen()">open</h2>
<h2 (click)="closeFullscreen()">close</h2>
```

**Component**

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}
  elem;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = document.documentElement;
  }

  openFullscreen() {
    if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
      this.elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }

  /* Close fullscreen */
  closeFullscreen() {
    if (this.document.exitFullscreen) {
      this.document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (this.document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (this.document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (this.document.msExitFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "current way" is 2018 - this is 2022: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71572615/1461862

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answer above are from 2018, nowdays to achieve compatibility in Chrome, Firefox, other browsers and mobile, I have determined that using `requestFullScreen` is enough

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Here is an example on to be able to toggle between full screen and normal screen:

```js
docElement: HTMLElement;
isFullScreen: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.docElement = document.documentElement;
}

toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!this.isFullScreen) {
      this.docElement.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
    this.isFullScreen = !this.isFullScreen;
}
```

The request to change to fullscreen can only be made when a user interacts with an element, for example a button

```html
<button (click)="toggleFullScreen()">SWITCH SCREEN MODE</button>
```

Comment: This approach will cause problems for cases where you enter or exit fullscreen mode without using the button, such as using *F11*, for example.

Comment: and for you which other answer is better or what is missing from mine ?

Comment: Use the `fullscreenElement` attribute of the *document* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenElement).

Comment: Well my code does not aim to detect if the currrent scrreen is in fullscreen mode, is actually outside the scope of the question, but is important to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

put the following code on the top of the component (before @Component) you want to trigger:

```
    interface FsDocument extends HTMLDocument {
      mozFullScreenElement?: Element;
      msFullscreenElement?: Element;
      msExitFullscreen?: () => void;
      mozCancelFullScreen?: () => void;
    }

    export function isFullScreen(): boolean {
      const fsDoc = <FsDocument> document;

      return !!(fsDoc.fullscreenElement || fsDoc.mozFullScreenElement || fsDoc.webkitFullscreenElement || fsDoc.msFullscreenElement);
    }

    interface FsDocumentElement extends HTMLElement {
      msRequestFullscreen?: () => void;
      mozRequestFullScreen?: () => void;
    }

    export function toggleFullScreen(): void {
      const fsDoc = <FsDocument> document;

      if (!isFullScreen()) {
        const fsDocElem = <FsDocumentElement> document.documentElement;

        if (fsDocElem.requestFullscreen)
          fsDocElem.requestFullscreen();
        else if (fsDocElem.msRequestFullscreen)
          fsDocElem.msRequestFullscreen();
        else if (fsDocElem.mozRequestFullScreen)
          fsDocElem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        else if (fsDocElem.webkitRequestFullscreen)
          fsDocElem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (fsDoc.exitFullscreen)
        fsDoc.exitFullscreen();
      else if (fsDoc.msExitFullscreen)
        fsDoc.msExitFullscreen();
      else if (fsDoc.mozCancelFullScreen)
        fsDoc.mozCancelFullScreen();
      else if (fsDoc.webkitExitFullscreen)
        fsDoc.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }

    export function setFullScreen(full: boolean): void {
      if (full !== isFullScreen())
        toggleFullScreen();
    }
```

and on the **ngOnInit** method make a call to the `setFullScreen(full: boolean)` function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setFullScreen(true);
}
```

Comment: Throws error-> core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'DashboardDefaultComponent' declared by the module 'DashboardDefaultModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: I was using this but in angular 7.0.0 this stopped working it will throw an error now.

Answer (score 0):

****This is the current "angular way" to do it.****

HTML:
Use This in Html:

```
(click)="openFullscreen()
```

NgOninit:

```
this.elem = document.documentElement;
```

TS:
Put this Function it will work...

```
 openFullscreen() {
if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
  this.elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  /* Firefox */
  this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
  this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  /* IE/Edge */
  this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}`]`
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Full Screen API`, which is provided by almost all browsers. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

In short, to display an `Element` in full-screen mode, you need to call `requestFullscreen()` on it. Exiting it is done via `exitFullscreen()`. To check if a browser is in full-screen mode, you can access the `fullscreenElement` document property. You can also handle the `fullscreenchange` event to be notified when full-screen mode is toggled.

Since this API has compatibility issues with Webkit-based browsers, I would suggest that you use the `webkit` prefix.

If you want to implement the full-screen feature in an 'Angular way,' I would suggest creating a directive. You can use a third-party library if you prefer, such as the [ngx-fullscreen-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-fullscreen-directive).