# How to hide the address bar in Ionic 4 (web platform) in mobile browser?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, fullscreen, mobile-browser

I had built a website using ionic4 and angular. But I have faced a big problem when I load it on mobile browser: when I scroll in the browser the address bar of the browser does not hide. But on the normal website which is built without ionic Framework, even in the angular project, when I scroll then the address bar of the browser hides. So how can I achieve this feature? I don't find any solution in the Ionic documentation and their forum.

Comment: what about this SO answer? does it work for Ionic 4 in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998594/how-to-make-google-chrome-go-full-screen-in-angular-4-application